# How to join two tables in Zend and read the resulting data

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db-select

I have the following query:

```
$usersTable = new Users();

$rowset = $usersTable->select()
    ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
    ->where( 'id = ?', $userId )
    ->join( 'Books', 'Books.userid = Users.id' );
```

However, I can't for the life of me figure out how to read the resulting rowset (the list of books associated with the user).

Would I do the following?

```
foreach ($book in $rowset->Books) {
    print_r($book["book_name"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you call $rowset is actually an sql expression.
This should work:

```
$usersTable = new Users();

$sql = $usersTable->select()
    ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
    ->where( 'id = ?', $userId )
    ->join( 'Books', 'Books.userid = Users.id' );
$rowset = $usersTable->getAdapter()->fetchAll($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
$sql = $this->select()
->setIntegrityCheck(false)
->where( 'id = ?', $userId )
->join( 'Books', 'Books.userid = Users.id' )
);
$rowset = $this->fetchRow($sql);
foreach ($rowset as $book) {
    print_r($book["book_name"]);
}
```

Is this going in your model?

Comment: I'm afraid this wont work, because you use joins in your select. You should use getAdapter before fetching.